# ImportError: No module named selenium on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, bots

I'm trying to build an easy python (python3) web scraper on a Mac. I installed Selenium in many different ways but always when I run my web scraping program the output says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/instagram_bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named selenium
[Finished in 0.6s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/username/Desktop/instagram_bot.py"]
[dir: /Users/username/Desktop]
[path:       /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Users/username/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

This is a common question but I have not found a solution yet.

Comment: Always share the entire error message/traceback. We need some information on your environment. From looking at the other comments in here, if you're struggling with this I would recommend just using Conda.

Comment: Now I uploaded the whole error message

Comment: It could be you have multiple Python versions installed - so `pip install` will not install to the conda version. Maybe try `conda install` ([see here for more info](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/install-packages/))

Comment: Ooh you were already using Conda. Can you share how you installed Selenium? My guess is that it was improperly installed, or the virtual environment is not being used.

Comment: @user101 Actually, Conda environments come with their own version of pip, so they technically could do `pip install`, although they really shouldn't. Then their's the whole issue of installing it in the correct environment ;)

Comment: I installed Selenium with pip3 (pip3 install selenium) because I usually don't use Anaconda

Comment: actually I'm using Sublime Text.. I'm so confused about all the files and packages I have on my Computer right now :( How can I check if I'm using the virtual env correctly?

Comment: @tcffm _because I usually don't use Anaconda_ ...2 minutes later... _I'm so confused about all the files and packages I have on my Computer right now :(_ ;p

Comment: _How can I check if I'm using the virtual env correctly?_ What do you mean? You should check out the [Conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/), they're pretty decent in my experience. You've told us very little about your environment, can you say more _about all the files and packages_ ?

Comment: I have different virtual environments. One is the environment called venv which I have created for the new project. In that environment I've installed Selenium and Pip. But when I run the code after activating venv the error I've postet above shows up. It seems like the the Program I'm working on doesn't even search in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium package is not installed correctly.

If you have `pip` installed you can install selenium like so.

**Windows:**

```
pip install selenium
```

**Unix:**

```
sudo pip install selenium
```

Comment: I'm using MacOS

Comment: Have you created virtual env for this project?

Comment: Also check selenium package under ../Library/Python/ver/site-packages

Comment: No, I've actually never done that

Comment: This is recommended way to have virtual env

Comment: Can you try this “sudo -H  pip3 install -U selenium”

Comment: I'll have to try creating the virtual env...

Comment: Okay. Can you try install selenium with -U switch as mentioned in above comment

Comment: I tried it, still doesn't work

Comment: Selenium seems to be installed correctly, but as soon as I try to run the code it gives me an error

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have more than one python installation.

You can install a module using your current python installation in the following way:

```sh
python -m pip install --user --upgrade --no-cache selenium
```

Comment: Tried it out, didn't work

Comment: Please run `pip freeze|grep -i selenium`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but unfortunately it didn't help